# Get a jquery onCLick listener on a button to fire before buttons ember action DOM updates

Tags: jquery, dom, ember.js

I have an ember action on a button that updates some DOM.

How can I get a seperate jquery `onCLick` listener on a button to fire before the buttons `ember action` does the DOM updates?

I want the onClick to happen before any dom update is finished in the actionHandler.

The `onClick` can only be in a component in the

application.hbs:

```
{{foo-comp currentRouteName=currentRouteName}}
```

Comment: maybe the more correct way would be to delay the action in the controller/view/component? like first running your code which you want to run first, then: Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', yourFunction);

Comment: @licancabur thanks but I can't do that cause I don't wan't to mod the application. My use case is an addon that is added to the app in a one off component that has the jquery listeners.

Comment: You can always try mousedown ;) but it would be ugly hack....

Comment: hmm I will try if I can't do it with extra placeholders for pending stuff. I wonder if I could pass a deferred promise outside of the action that somehow my component could use?

Comment: What exactly you mean by DOM update?

Comment: So when the DOM updates I have some mutationevents that fire, however I don't want them to fire before my jquery click has fired @Vaibhav

Comment: In view, you can handle, click event, and then you can check $(event.target).hasClass('someButtonClass').....then you can handle that button click..and if you want to send some action you can send action from view to controller.

Comment: @Vaibhav I can't all code has to be in the component  used in application.hbs as shown in my edited answer/

Comment: We can use sendAction method from coponent and rest of the functionality would be same. Only thing is we have to define an action in controller you want to handle. and one action property mentioned in component handlebar

Comment: Can you give some code, I would only like this code to sit in application controller and pass it to the component.